# Flutter, how to automatically animate without a button trigger

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have some animation code that changes background color infinitely

but the problem is I want to do this without a button trigger

and I want this to be automated at first time (when it's firstly loading)

below is code

I`m so stuck could anyone help please

the purpose is to animate without a trigger, it automatically runs animation that changes background

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenTime extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_ScreenTimeState createState() => _ScreenTimeState();
}

class _ScreenTimeState extends State<ScreenTime> {
  List<Color> colorList = [
  Colors.red,
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.yellow
 ];
List<Alignment> alignmentList = [
  Alignment.bottomLeft,
  Alignment.bottomRight,
  Alignment.topRight,
  Alignment.topLeft,
];
 int index = 0;
 Color bottomColor = Colors.black54;
 Color topColor = Colors.white10;
 Alignment begin = Alignment.bottomLeft;
 Alignment end = Alignment.topRight;


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          onEnd: () {
            setState(() {
              index = index + 1;
              // animate the color
              bottomColor = colorList[index % colorList.length];
              topColor = colorList[(index + 1) % colorList.length];

              //// animate the alignment
              // begin = alignmentList[index % alignmentList.length];
              // end = alignmentList[(index + 2) % alignmentList.length];
            });
          },
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: begin, end: end, colors: [bottomColor, topColor])),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                bottomColor = Colors.blue;
              });
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep as much as your original implementation as possible while fixing the problem, doing

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {bottomColor = Colors.blue;}));
```

in `initState` would not pose an issue. This is as long as it's done in `initState`. Calling it in `build` would lead to an undesirable extra infinite loop.

However, using an [`AnimationController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) on `repeat` would almost certainly be a cleaner implmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
bool selected = false;

@override
void initState() {
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
  setState(() {
    selected = true;
  });
});
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    color: Colors.white
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        AnimatedAlign(
          alignment: selected ? Alignment.topRight : Alignment.bottomLeft,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: const FlutterLogo(size: 50.0),
        ),
      ],
    ));}
```

This Will automatically starts the animation. You can change the duration or animation type also.